# Exporting Seurat Object Data by Cluster

Tags: r, export-to-csv, seurat

I'm using Seurat to perform a single cell analysis and am interested in exporting the data for all cells within each of my clusters. I tried to use the below code but have had no success.

My Seurat object is called `Patients`. I also attached a screenshot of my Seurat object. I am looking to extract all the clusters (i.e. `Ductal1`, `Macrophage1`, `Macrophage2`, etc...)

```
meta.data.cluster <- unique(x = Patients@meta.data$active.ident)

for(group in meta.data.cluster) {
  group.cells <- WhichCells(object = Patients, subset.name = "active.ident" , accept.value = group)
  data_to_write_out <- as.data.frame(x = as.matrix(x = Patients@raw.data[, group.cells]))
  write.csv(x = data_to_write_out, row.names = TRUE, file = paste0(save_dir,"/",group, "_cluster_outfile.csv"))
}
```

[image: Seurat object in RStudio]

I am new to R and coding so any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because there is no `active.ident` column under your metadata. For example if we use an example dataset like yours and set the ident:

```
library(Seurat)

M = matrix(rnbinom(5000,mu=20,size=1),ncol=50)
colnames(M) = paste0("P",1:50)
rownames(M) = paste0("gene",1:100)

Patients = CreateSeuratObject(M)
Patients$grp = sample(c("Ductal1","Macrophage1","Macrophage2"),50,replace=TRUE)
Idents(Patients) = Patients$grp
```

You can see this line of code gives you no value:

```
meta.data.cluster <- unique(x = Patients@meta.data$active.ident)
meta.data.cluster
NULL
```

You can do:

```
meta.data.cluster <- unique(Idents(Patients))

for(group in meta.data.cluster) {
  group.cells <- WhichCells(object = Patients, idents = group)
  data_to_write_out <- as.data.frame(GetAssayData(Patients,slot = 'counts')[,group.cells])
  write.csv(data_to_write_out, row.names = TRUE, file = paste0(save_dir,"/",group, "_cluster_outfile.csv"))
}
```

Note also you can get the counts out using `GetAssayData` . You can subset one group and write out like this:

```
wh <- which(Idents(Patients) =="Macrophage1" )
da = as.data.frame(GetAssayData(Patients,slot = 'counts')[,wh])
write.csv(da,...)
```

Comment: Thank you! Also curious, if I wanted to select just one cell cluster (i.e. Macrophage 1) is there a way to subset using the function WhichCells? Right now I am just getting 1 .csv file out that I believe has all the clusters

Comment: meta.data.cluster <- unique(Idents(Patients))

for(group in meta.data.cluster) {
  group.cells <- WhichCells(object = Patients, idents= group)
  data_to_write_out <- as.data.frame(GetAssayData(Patients,slot = 'counts')[,group.cells])
  write.csv(data_to_write_out, row.names = TRUE, file = paste0(group, "_cluster_outfile.csv"))
}

Comment: This is my code currently. The output file doesn't seem to subset the clusters for some reason? Also where should I be placing the wh = which(Idents(Patients) == "Macrophage1") ; Patients[,wh] ? Sorry I am new to coding :(

Comment: ok the code works. "The output file doesn't seem to subset the clusters for some reason?" no idea what this would be because I cannot see your data. If you read in the output csv, you should get the same number of columns as the number of cells that fit it